# nfs server slow

Tags: nfs

I'm trying to figure out why my nfs server is so slow.

My server is nfs v3, OS is debian 11.
I used 6x 500GB sata drives and configured RAID0 on them during OS installation.

nfsstat is showing high badfmt but I cant find anywhere what this means.

```
root@debian-bkp:~# nfsstat -s
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badfmt     badauth    badclnt
610192     222856     222856     0          0

Server nfs v3:
null             getattr          setattr          lookup           access
0         0%     45876    10%     0         0%     348       0%     165       0%
readlink         read             write            create           mkdir
0         0%     0         0%     389213   89%     30        0%     12        0%
symlink          mknod            remove           rmdir            rename
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%
link             readdir          readdirplus      fsstat           fsinfo
0         0%     0         0%     22        0%     123       0%     1         0%
pathconf         commit
0         0%     0         0%

root@debian-bkp:~# iostat -x 15
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0,07    0,02    7,54    0,15    0,00   92,23

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
dm-0             0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00   11,07   8474,40     0,00   0,00   15,83   765,76    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,18  18,56
dm-1             0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00
md0              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00   33,93  12607,73     0,00   0,00    0,00   371,54    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,00   0,00
sda              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    4,73   1430,40     0,60  11,25   10,86   302,20    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,05   5,55
sdb              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    5,73   1438,67     1,27  18,10    8,36   250,93    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,05   6,48
sdc              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    4,60   1406,13     0,67  12,66   13,48   305,68    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,06   6,69
sdd              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    5,07   1399,47     0,40   7,32    6,83   276,21    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,03   5,31
sde              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    5,07   1399,47     0,40   7,32    8,21   276,21    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,04   5,92
sdf              0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    4,60   1399,47     0,60  11,54   15,51   304,23    0,00      0,00     0,00   0,00    0,00     0,00    0,00    0,00    0,07   6,48
sdg  


root@debian-bkp:~# exportfs -v
/nfs/synology   10.0.0.224/255.0.0.0(rw,async,wdelay,root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,root_squash,no_all_squash)
/nfs/hv02       10.0.0.220/255.0.0.0(rw,async,wdelay,root_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,secure,root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

thanks in advance for any sugggestions.

Comment: NFS v3 indicates you have some important external restrictions that you forgot to mention! This probably has influences on any solution we could offer. So please explain why you're using a standard that's been superseded for 22 years!

Comment: Especially, since this is about performance, and v4 has, among a lot of other important changes, a significant improvement in terms of performance with "modern" (read: not from 1995) networking and storage architectures. If performance matters, I'd assume v3 is a non-starter, but here we are, left to wonder why we're on v3!

Comment: didn't know that there are some significant improvements in v4. the only reason I configured v3 was that I couldn't figure out why I cannot connect to it from ESXi webconsole when it was v4 :) looks like I need to try harder.